# Quicklisp's file setup.lisp does not load correctly

Tags: eclipse, installation, common-lisp, quicklisp, abcl

Hi all and thank you for reading my issue.

I can't load quicklisp's file setup.lisp from the lisp console.

It throws the following error:

Error loading C:/quicklisp/setup.lisp at line 134 (offset 5035)
THREAD "main" {1DD02175}: Debugger invoked on condition of type PROGRAM-ERROR
Wrong number of arguments for SPECIAL-OPERATOR THROW; 2 expected.

I'm loading it using ABCL (Armed Bear Common Lisp) from eclipse, just as the ABCL user's manual says.

> For example, Quicklisp ([Bea]) may be completely installed from the REPL
>   as the single form:
>   CL-USER > (load "http://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp")
>   will load and execute the Quicklisp setup code.

The next step is to run `(quicklisp-quickstart:install)` , that works fine until it loads the setup.lisp file.

When I restart the app, I do the same and it tells me that quicklisp it's already installed and I need to load the setup.lisp file, but throws the same error as I posted before.

Comment: Do you have anything funny in directories scanned for the ASDF registry?  I had problems like circular symlinks at that point; maybe there is a broken `.asd` file there somewhere?

Comment: @Svante Nothing like that, I did not change anything. I was trying it on windows 10, so when I was tired of trying the impossible I followed the same steps in the same enviroment but in linux, specifically in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Javierdds, I was going to say, `C:/quicklisp/setup.lisp` is the issue, particularly the `C:` part. :-) Glad that it works on *nix.

Answer (score 0):

As an optimization to loading Quicklisp, abcl attempts to compile the `quicklisp/setup.lisp` source artifact.  If this gets out of sync, and the provided restart doesn't handle it, the user may manually clear the situation with:

```sh
rm ~/quicklisp/setup.abcl
```

TODO: offer a better interactive restart to recompile the fasl